# How to find the highest and lowest numbers from a loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I add into this program to find the highest and lowest numbers? I have tried a few different things but it just keeps giving me the last number I enter as both.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Laskenta</title>
<script>

var yht=0; //sum
var luku=0; //number
var laske; //count

laske=Number(prompt("how many numbers would you like to add?"))
for (var i=0; i<laske; i++){luku = Number(prompt("give number", "number")); 

yht=yht+luku;

} 
while(i<laske);

document.write("the sum of the numbers you entered is " ,yht, "<br>");
document.write (" and the average is o " + yht/laske);
```

Ive translated most of it from Finnish and put next to what is still in Finnish the meanings next to it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first set of operations addresses your desired to do these tasks in a loop, but you don't really need a traditional loop to do these tasks. The new [spread operator along with Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and the [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method can easily get you the max value, the sum or the average.

```js
var result = null;
var nums = [];

// Remember, a propmt will always return a string, you must convert that
// to a number if you want to do math with it.
var count = parseInt(prompt("How many numbers do you want to work with?"), 10);

// Build up the input values into an array:
for(var i = 0; i < count; ++i){
  nums.push(parseInt(prompt("Enter number " + (i + 1)),10));
}

// The "traditional" way to get the max value from a loop would be to
// compare the value that you are iterating and the next value in the
// array and store the higehr one:
var max = null;
var sum = 0;
for(var x = 0; x < nums.length-1; ++x){
     max = (nums[x] > nums[x + 1]) ? nums[x] : nums[x + 1];
     sum += nums[x];
}
console.log("Max number is: " + max);

var sum = 0;
for(var y = 0; y < nums.length; ++y){
     sum += nums[y];
}
console.log("Sum is: " + sum);
console.log("Average is: " + sum / nums.length);
  
// *******************************************************************************
// But, we have much better ways of doing these jobs:
console.log("Max number is: " + Math.max(...nums));

result = nums.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
  return accumulator + currentValue;
});

console.log("The sum is: " + result);
console.log("The average is: " + result / nums.length);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am just starting out and this question comes from the topic of loops. It says as a hint to take the first number and use that as what to compare against. How can I compare against an unknown? I tried setting them as 0 but then I get both come back as the last number I enter.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var yht=0; //sum
var luku=0; //number
var laske; //count
var highest;
var lowest;

laske=Number(prompt("how many numbers would you like to add?"))
for (var i=0; i<laske; i++){luku = Number(prompt("give number", "number")); 
if (i == 0) {
highest = luku;
lowest = luku;
}
else {
  if (luku > highest) highest = luku;
  if (luku < lowest) lowest = luku;
}
yht=yht+luku;

} 
while(i<laske);

document.write("the sum of the numbers you entered is " ,yht, "<br>");
document.write (" and the average is o " + yht/laske); 
document.write("<br />Highest value="+highest);
document.write("<br />Lowest value="+lowest);
```

Add two variables in the code to track highest and lowest values entered.  Set the first number entered to both highest and lowest.  Then when a new low  is encountered, replace lowest.  When a new high value is encountered replace highest.

Comment: arghhh thank you! I could kick myself! I had done that but not wrote the if (i== 0) bit. I just kept getting back the the last number I had entered then. Ive been sat hours trying to figure it out. :D

Comment: Glad to help.  Please accept my answer if it indeed answered your question.